# How to Pass a String with Spaces From Command Line to SQL

Tags: sql, command-line, command-line-arguments

I am using command line in Windows 7 to read rows of variables from a CSV, pass those variables into a SQL command, and execute that SQL command for each row in the CSV. This works fine, I believe. Where I am running into trouble is when my variables contain spaces, such as strings that need to be input into my database.

My code looks like this:

Command line:

`C:\Users\me>(sqlcmd -S npl-sql01 -d OnBaseTEST -i "C:\Users\me\myquery.sql" -v var1="\Policy Term\Policy\" var2= 'REPORT' var3= 'Commercial' )`

Where `var1`, `var2`, and `var3` are variables in the SQL query that get their values from a CSV.

SQL query:

`INSERT INTO testdb (column1, column2, column3)
SELECT $(var1), $(var2), $(var3), od.value
FROM otherdatabase AS od
WHERE od.identifier = 24`

When I wrap the variable `np` in single quotes, the command line chokes up on the space in the path. When I wrap it in double quotes, SQL appears to be treating it as a column name rather than a value to be put into a column ([based off of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695778/sql-server-invalid-column-name-error-when-inserting-into-excel-linked-server)). I have also tried wrapping with two sets of quotes, e.g. `"'a string'"` and `'"a string"'`, with no luck. How should I be writing out this string with spaces so that both command line and SQL can understand it?

Edit: For some reason, removing the trailing variable `var3` allows the script to work as intended when the string is wrapped with `"'two types of quotes'"`

Comment: my idea would be to wrap the string vars in the SQL Query and use double quotes when assigning: `INSERT INTO testdb (column1, column2, column3) SELECT '$(var1)', '$(var2)', '$(var3)', od.value FROM otherdatabase AS od WHERE od.identifier = 24`

Comment: @niyou that did it, can you put it as an answer so that I can mark it as such?